# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rjags’

Tags: r, environment-variables, jags, rjags, renv

I have a M1 Macbook Pro running OS Big Sur and just tried to install `rjags` and `JAGS`. I downloaded JAGS from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/ without a problem, and ran `install_packages("rjags")`, but when I run `library(rjags)` I get this error:

```
Loading required package: coda
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rjags’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rjags', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Users/afredston/Library/Caches/org.R-project.R/R/renv/cache/v5/R-4.1/aarch64-apple-darwin20/rjags/4-12/e8a71b3a154c8e68c152b4cfbebfdd97/rjags/libs/rjags.so':
  dlopen(/Users/afredston/Library/Caches/org.R-project.R/R/renv/cache/v5/R-4.1/aarch64-apple-darwin20/rjags/4-12/e8a71b3a154c8e68c152b4cfbebfdd97/rjags/libs/rjags.so, 10): Library not loaded: /opt/R/arm64/lib/libjags.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/afredston/Library/Caches/org.R-project.R/R/renv/cache/v5/R-4.1/aarch64-apple-darwin20/rjags/4-12/e8a71b3a154c8e68c152b4cfbebfdd97/rjags/libs/rjags.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I understand this means that R cannot "find" the installation of JAGS. I am using `renv` for this project, but even if I deactivate it and re-run `install_packages("rjags")` and `library(rjags)` I get the error (just with different file paths):

```
Loading required package: coda
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rjags’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rjags', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/rjags/libs/rjags.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/rjags/libs/rjags.so, 10): Library not loaded: /opt/R/arm64/lib/libjags.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/rjags/libs/rjags.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I'm a stats person without much back-end computer expertise so I'd appreciate help resolving this!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/support-requests/8/) for a similar post.

So have you installed the correct version of JAGS on your Apple computer?

Essentially, rjags is an R interface and it needs an installed JAGS (a back-end you mentioned) to function.

Follow the instructions [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/610037/thread/07e08a3605/) to install JAGS on Apple computers with M1 chips.

Also from the link above (from JAGS development team):

> A readme file is provided in the disk image - please do read it.
> If you find that rjags fails to load after installation of JAGS,
> make sure you have installed the Mavericks or El Capitan binary of
> R from CRAN.  If you really need the Snow Leopard build of R (or if
> you compiled R yourself) you will have to compile JAGS from source.

> If you have followed the instructions above (and in the relevant
> README file) and are still having problems with installation of
> these binaries, please let us know via the JAGS discussion forum.

PS: I would comment if I could, but I am new here and don't have enough points to do so.

Comment: I opened the installer that I downloaded and followed the prompts to install JAGS. Is that what you meant?

Comment: yes. "Reason: image not found" means rjags couldn't find the needed files. Also see the updated answer.

Comment: Running `brew install pkg-config; brew install jags` in the terminal prior to installing  the package in R did the trick for me, which is shown in the second link above or [JAGS installation](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/610037/thread/07e08a3605/).